# Uncaught TypeError: n.wrap is not a function in kendo grid

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using kendo grid with Jquery, When I am trying to set new data in the kendo grid and trying to refresh, the grid is loaded as expected but after that if I try to edit a field, it's throwing an exception.

[image]

Comment: Please put your code and what you have tried

Comment: What column types are you using? What data format? What templates? What editors? All we know is that there is no such bug at https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues .